# How to play an object of youtube videos on JWPlayer PHP

Tags: php, jwplayer

I have this object with youtube video keys:

```
{
  "id": 321612,
  "results": [
    {
      "id": "589219bfc3a368096a009a41",
      "iso_639_1": "en",
      "iso_3166_1": "US",
      "key": "tWapqpCEO7Y",
      "name": "Belle Motion Poster",
      "site": "YouTube",
      "size": 720,
      "type": "Clip"
    },
    {
      "id": "5743a07a9251414c0d000605",
      "iso_639_1": "en",
      "iso_3166_1": "US",
      "key": "c38r-SAnTWM",
      "name": "Official US Teaser Trailer",
      "site": "YouTube",
      "size": 1080,
      "type": "Trailer"
    },
    {
      "id": "589219d3c3a36809660098dd",
      "iso_639_1": "en",
      "iso_3166_1": "US",
      "key": "bgeSXHvPoBI",
      "name": "Lumiere Motion Poster",
      "site": "YouTube",
      "size": 720,
      "type": "Clip"
    }
}
```

What I want to do is play this as a playlist on a Jwplayer.

```
<div id="myElement"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var playerInstance = jwplayer("myElement");
playerInstance.setup({
   'image': '{{$movie->poster_path}}',
    file: '//www.youtube.com/watch?v={{reset($movievideo)->key}}',
});
</script>
```

How can I achieve this, so that when the first video ends, the next on the object list is played?